# HttpPostedFileBase sometime null on ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app and my action should received a `HttpPostedFileBase` in parameter. I am trying to understand how the parameter could be `null`.

It happens time to time in my production environment and I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: Is the input set as "required" so that the user has to attach a file?

Comment: Yes, the file must be provided.